# Extracting the contents of a zip file with overwrite all mode in CentOS 5

Tags: centos, zip

How can I `unzip` a `zip` file which contains different directories and sub directories with the overwrite mode?
I mean I want the zipped contents to overwrites any existing files (be it old be it new).
I have read about the `unzip` command , but it seems it doesn't overwrite any sub directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When doing something like this it will never replace the directory if it exists, it will create any files in the directory that do not already exist and replace any files that do.

Effectively it combines/updates the directory.

Without `rm`ing the directory prior to unzipping I'm pretty sure you cannot achieve what you are trying to do.

The overwrite all mode you are referring to (-o) will simply overwrite files without asking.

Comment: I don't want the directories or sub directories to be recreated, i want their files to be replaced.any luck now?

Comment: as h3rrmiller said, as long as you are not deleting anything, when you extract the zip file at the base of the tree where it was created, it will by default overwrite existing files, create files and directories that didn't exist and and ignore anything that was already there but it didn't have within the archive.

Comment: @Hossein Directories wont be overwritten with the unzip process (or any inflation process). only files. any directories that already exist will be "updated".

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
unzip -o <filepath/zipfile.zip> -d <path where you want files>
```